# WinUI 3 ListView - how to select item programmatically in mvvm?

Tags: c#, listview, mvvm, winui-3

We have an observable collection `SelectedPartys` if user interacts with the listview we add/remove in code behind.

```xml
<ListView
    x:Name="LV_Partys"
    IsMultiSelectCheckBoxEnabled="True"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.PartysOC, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectionChanged="LV_Partys_SelectionChanged"
    SelectionMode="Extended">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <Grid Margin="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                </StackPanel>

            </Grid>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

```cs
private ObservableCollection<Party> partysOC;
public ObservableCollection<Party> PartysOC
{
    get => partysOC;
    set => Set(ref partysOC, value);
}

private void LV_Partys_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var added_items = e.AddedItems.Cast<Party>().ToList();
    foreach (var item in added_items)
    {
        ViewModel.SelectedPartys.Add(item);
    }

    var removed_items = e.RemovedItems.Cast<Party>().ToList();
    foreach (var item in removed_items)
    {
        ViewModel.SelectedPartys.Remove(item);
    }

    ViewModel.SelectedPartyChanged();
}
```

We need to save the ListViews selected items in Db and then restore them ***pre-selected*** in the ListView, to do this I believe we need to select an item programatically, how can we do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't bind to `SelectedItems`, you might need to create a  control derived from `ListView`:

**CustomListView.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;

namespace ListViews;

public class CustomListView : ListView
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(SelectedItemsSource),
        typeof(object),
        typeof(CustomListView),
        new PropertyMetadata(default, (d, e) =>
        {
            (d as CustomListView)?.UpdateSelectedItemsSource();
        }));

    public object SelectedItemsSource
    {
        get => (object)GetValue(SelectedItemsSourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(SelectedItemsSourceProperty, value);
    }

    private CollectionViewSource? SelectedItemsSourceViewSource { get; set; }

    private ICollectionView? SelectedItemsSourceView { get; set; }

    private void UpdateSelectedItemsSource()
    {
        if (SelectedItemsSourceView is not null)
        {
            SelectedItemsSourceView.VectorChanged -= SelectedItemsSourceView_VectorChanged;
        }

        SelectedItemsSourceViewSource = new()
        {
            Source = SelectedItemsSource
        };

        SelectedItemsSourceView = SelectedItemsSourceViewSource.View;
        SelectedItemsSourceView.VectorChanged += SelectedItemsSourceView_VectorChanged;
    }

    private void SelectedItemsSourceView_VectorChanged(IObservableVector<object> sender, IVectorChangedEventArgs @event)
    {
        switch (@event.CollectionChange)
        {
            case CollectionChange.Reset:
                SelectedItems.Clear();
                break;

            case CollectionChange.ItemInserted:
                if (SelectedItemsSourceView?.Count >= @event.Index)
                {
                    SelectedItems.Add(SelectedItemsSourceView[(int)@event.Index]);
                }
                break;

            case CollectionChange.ItemRemoved:
                if (SelectedItemsSourceView?.Count >= @event.Index)
                {
                    SelectedItems.Remove(SelectedItemsSourceView[(int)@event.Index]);
                }
                break;

            case CollectionChange.ItemChanged:
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<local:CustomListView
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items, Mode=OneWay}"
    SelectedItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedItems, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Item">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Id}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</local:CustomListView>
```

Comment: Thanks, i will take a look at this. For now I have created a solution that ive posted that does the job but needs to use MVVM message bus.

Comment: ListView does have a SelectedItems property, such a shame MS made it readonly and not a DP.

Comment: Works a treat, appreciate it. Cant believe this isnt standard fuctionality.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method on the WinUI 3 ListView called `YourListView.SelectRange()`

It isnt available on a ListView in xaml so I call it in code behind via a MVVM messenging call.

The Views Code Behind file

```
public CodeBehindConstructor()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    // Rx ListView Select items
    WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<Msg_ListView_SelectItems>(this, (r, msg) =>
    {
        SelectParty(msg.Start, msg.Length);
    });
}


public void SelectParty(int start, uint length)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"SelectParty  start {start}   len {length}");
    LV_Partys.SelectRange(new ItemIndexRange(start, length));
}
```

The ViewModel

```
    // Select 1st Party 
    WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new Msg_ListView_SelectItems { Start = 0, Length = 1});// Start is 0 based, Length isnt it starts at 1

    // Select 2nd Party 
    WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new Msg_ListView_SelectItems { Start = 1, Length = 1 });
```

Msg_ListView_SelectItems class

```
public class Msg_ListView_SelectItems
{
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public uint Length { get; set; }
}
```

If your ListViews selection mode is `Multiple` or `Extended` then `.SelectRange()` selects ***one*** consecutive lot of items, so you can call `SelectRange` more than once for items that are not in consecutive order.